# Firebase otp working for android device and not for ios device in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, onesignal

Not able to understand the issue when i run flutter app in android device everything is working superb but no otp and notification when i am running same app in ios device

Answer (score 1):

go to your developer apple account, then navigate to key the register your app the APNs then download the p8 file and upload it to console.firebase...